# Create or edit .slx programmatically in standalone Matlab GUI

Tags: matlab, model, edit, simulink, matlab-compiler

I was wondering if there is a smart way to modify or merge already existing `.slx` models programmatically in MATLAB standalone mode.
I already thought to do that with open_system command but unfortunately it is not supported in standalone mode.

I also thought to convert the `.slx` into `.xml` using the save_system and then edit the `.xml`, but then I don't know how to pack it back to `.slx` once that modifications are ended.

If there is another more immediate strategy that Mathworks provides, that I don't know, please tell me.

Comment: Simulink commands are not supported by the MATLAB Compiler - hence, by definition, there is no "more immediate strategy that MathWorks provides" for them to work.

Comment: Any other possible workaround? Because if I open as rar the slx I can see the xml inside. And if I try to access, edit one of them and then exit and exit (accepting the winrar msg to update the slx "archive") , I can find the modifications of value and blocks also in the new slx file. So my question now is: there is a way to open the slx as an archive and do the modification programmatically and save it back without corrupt the slx? Thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: You can make `system` calls from a compiled executable, and you can edit text files, so with some work I'd expect you to be able to edit and re-save the `slx` archive.